# Django/Ajax Get "data" returning html from firing page instead of target view

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm using the following simple AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('#currentNodes').attr('target'),
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

It is supposed to grab the target from the following element:

```
<p><a href="{% url "current_nodes" view.slug %}" id="currentNodes">Test</a></p>
```

When I click on the above element, my browser displays the HTML I set up in my **views.py**:

```
def current_nodes(request, slug):
    html = "<html><body>Smoke Test for {}</body></html>".format(slug)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

at the url defined in my **urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/current_nodes/$', current_nodes, name="current_nodes"),
```

But according to `console.log`, the Ajax call from this link receives the response that comes from the view that is serving the current page, not the one that I ask for in the target. Sure enough, if I try to do anything with it, it displays the full html of the template I am on, rather than plugging in the html I'm trying to process.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#currentNodes` is an `a` element. It doesn't have a `target` attribute; it has an `href`.

```
url: $('#currentNodes').attr('href'),
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `target` is not defined. try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('#currentNodes').attr('href'),
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('error');
    }
});
```